# Doctrine joinColumns on different tables (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am stucked to a problem building the database with Dcotrine and YAML.

I have the following tables 'product', 'station' and 'station_description'.

I want to store the description of the 'station' in dependent on the station and the product. For Example I have the following setup:

Station_A and Product_1 --> show Description 1

Station_A and Product_2 --> show Description 2

Station_B and Product_1 --> show Description 3

I knew exactly how I would solve the problem if I use SQL, but with Doctrine I find no approach how to declare the relations.

Does anyone have a solution to that problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All the relation you can perform in SQL, can be configurated using the official doc :http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: I believe this example is similar to what you want to achieve:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata

Comment: Thanks igorshmigor. I read the docs over and over, but I didn't recognized this part.